# Finding Mean Value Pandas While Having String

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, mean

I have a 20*5 data table and I want to find the mean value of one of the columns which is the price column. I know I have to use this method for finding the mean value

```
mean= df["price"].mean()
```

the problem is that in my data file, the prices are not integers and they are strings and all of them are written in this format e.x.(2000dollars not just 2000). How can I remove those currencies from the numbers and then finding the mean value of the numbers?(The currencies are all the same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try normalising you data first,

```
df["price"] = df["price"].apply(lambda x: float(x.replace("dollars", "")))
```

I am assuming the prices are stored like 5000dollars, if you have any other abnormality, you can replace it with empty value.

or if you dont wanna update this columns entry, you can make a new column and use that one for mean,

```
df["new_price"] = df["price"].apply(lambda x: float(x.replace("dollars", "")))
```

Comment: Also I faced another problem now. The numbers are written in this format (200,000) so it gives me error while converting them to float. Is there any way with this method to remove those "," signs as well?

Comment: do .replace(",", "") also to remove ","

Comment: Hello @sidshrivastav, while your answer is also valid, but `.apply()` is considered quite slow when the number of rows grows large.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['price'].str.replace('dollars', '').astype('float').mean()
```